# Pattern matching, does not begin with zero

Tags: php, javascript, design-patterns, matching

I have a field where user input their age, and I want to do some error checking. If the user enter the digit '0' and click `submit`, it will display an error saying they can't begin with a zero. But I also want to allow an age that contain the digit zero, such as age 20. I don't know how to not allow someone to enter a beginning digit of 0.

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$age_numeric = preg_match("/^(^[1-9]){1,}$/", $age);
?>
//some more code
<?php if (!$age_numeric) echo "age can only be numeric."; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why not just

```
$age_numeric = preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]*$/", $age);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

This regexp matches valid numbers without leading zeros:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

use `is_numeric`

```
if(!empty($age) && is_numeric($age)) {
  echo 'valid age';
} else {
  echo 'invalid age';
}
```

// Sample output

```
$age = 0; // invalid age
$age = ''; // invalid age
$age = 'lkjsd'; // invalid age
$age = 12a; // invalid age
$age = 1; // valid age
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$begin_with_zero = preg_match("/^0/", $age);
<?php if ($begin_with_zero) echo "Can't begin with zero."; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expressions:

```
if (is_numeric($age) && strspn($age, '0') == 0) {
    // $age is numeric and doesn't start with "0"
}
```

See also: [`strspn()`](http://php.net/strspn)